# Visualisation step before being able to sign

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to create the following workflow for one signer in DocuSign : 
- The signer access to an embeddded view of DocuSign. In this view, he can see the documents, refuse to sign or ask for more information **but he can't sign anything or complete any field**.
- He then clicks on "Finish", is redirected to my application.
- In my application, he has several steps to pass into (like giving bank information).
- Then, he can finally access to another emebdded view of DocuSign where he can sign, refuse to sign or ask for more information.

Today, I do not know how to make step 1 (visualisation without signing). Do you have any idea or solution to achieve this step ?

I'm aware of the "Certified copy" role but it's not what I want : a certified cannot refused to sign or ask for more information.

I've tried to simply define no tabs for this signer (both signer.setTabs(null) and signer.setTabs(new Tabs())). But DocuSign gives the possibility to the signer  to add every field he wants, where he wants. Of course, it isn't the behaviour I'm looking for.

I'm using the [REST Api in Java.](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-java-client)

Answer (score 0):

Even though a recipient may be defined as a "Signer" role, that does not necessarily mean there needs to be a signature/initials tab on the document. I'd recommend adding the desired optional/required fields, and do not specify any signature tabs. Once all required fields have been met on the document the signer/recipient will be able to hit Finish.